Refreshing Lava Rock and Rock Wool for Gas Fireplace
I am cleaning, sprucing up my 25-year-old gas fire place inside my home.  I see there are three layers under the fake logs: some silica sand, 1/4" (or so) lava rock/gravel, and rock wool.
1) Anything in particular I should pay attention to when doing this, e.g. should I keep log placement exactly as is for any reason?  (there seemed to be some concerns about this as I researched.) Or any other considerations?
2) I guess I could completely clean out the whole insert and start from scratch with sand, then lava rock, then rock wool, then replace logs.  Any reason to be this particular?  Or does it make more sense to just (intelligently) dump/supplement new stuff on top of what's there
3) I noticed a wide variation in prices for 6 oz bags of rock wool on Amazon, like double in some cases.  Is there any issue with the quality or suitability or whatever of this stuff, or is one bag of rock wool pretty much indistinguishable from another, i.e. rock wool is rock wool is rock wool?
4) While the fireplace has seen very little use over the last 25 years, it may be that simple passage of time might indicate that a replcement of thermocouple/thermopile is warranted.  Any way to tell beforehand?  Or should I just do it because...?
